# Como utilizar classe FutureTask corretamente?

Tags: java, paralelismo

Estou querendo calcular a quantidade de números que podem ser divididos por um divisor sem resto paralelamente.

O problema é o resultado do método sempre retornar a metade do que deveria, parece que só uma `thread` está sendo executada. Olhando o `ArrayList` de FutureTask realmente eu vi que uma está com o valor que deveria após o cálculo e a outra está com zero.

Por que isso está acontecendo?

```
  public static int calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(final int first, final int last, final int divisor)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    int amount = 0;
    int threadNum = 2;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadNum);
    List<FutureTask<Integer>> taskList = new ArrayList<FutureTask<Integer>>();

    int quantidadeFatiasPorThread =  (last / threadNum);

    System.out.println("Quantidade: "+quantidadeFatiasPorThread);
    primeiro =0; ultimo = primeiro+quantidadeFatiasPorThread;

    arrayFutureTasks = new FutureTask[threadNum];
    for(int i = 0; i< threadNum;i++){
        System.out.println(i+" "+threadNum);
         System.out.println("primeiro :"+primeiro+" ultimo: "+ultimo);
        arrayFutureTasks[i] = new FutureTask<Integer>(new Callable<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call() {
                return FutureTaskDemo.calcularQuantidadeDivisivelSerial(primeiro, ultimo, divisor);
            }
        });

        taskList.add(arrayFutureTasks[i]);
        executor.execute(arrayFutureTasks[i]);

        primeiro = ultimo+1;
        ultimo +=quantidadeFatiasPorThread;

        if(ultimo > last){

            int quantidadeMais = ultimo - last;
            ultimo = ultimo - quantidadeMais;

        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < threadNum; j++) {

        FutureTask<Integer> futureTask = taskList.get(j);
        amount += futureTask.get();

    }

    executor.shutdown();

    return amount;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, a sua questão sofre de alguns problemas:

- O seu código tem vários erros de compilação cuja correção não é trivial. Primeiramente, as variáveis `primeiro` e `ultimo` não foram declaradas, e devido ao modificador `final` nos parâmetros, também não pode ser apenas um simples caso de ter esquecido de renomear o `first` e o `last`, ainda mais dado o fato de que você claramente usa `ultimo` e `last` como sendo duas variáveis distintas.
- Você também não forneceu o código do método `calcularQuantidadeDivisivelSerial`, deixando difícil para nós vermos o que está acontecendo, ainda mais se puder haver algum problema dentro deste método.
- A variável `arrayFutureTasks` também não foi declarada e claramente não é a mesma coisa que `taskList`. E isso é mais um motivo pelo qual o código não compila.
- Você não informou quais são os valores que você usou na função para obter o resultado que você obteve, e sem isso fica difícil responder a sua pergunta "*Olhando o arrayList de FutureTask realmente eu vi que uma está com o valor que deveria após o cálculo e a outra está com zero, mas por que isso está acontecendo?*".

Esses problemas acima são motivo suficiente para fechar a sua pergunta como "***não é claro o que você está perguntando***", mas vou tentar responder mesmo assim.

---

Primeiro vamos consertar os problemas de compilação:

1. Vou assumir que o nome da classe é `FutureTaskDemo` e colocar os `imports` necessários.
2. O método `calcularQuantidadeDivisivelSerial`:

```java
    public static int calcularQuantidadeDivisivelSerial(int first, int last, int divisor) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
            if (i % divisor == 0) result++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

3. Vou supor que `primeiro` e `ultimo` devessem ser declarados na primeira vez em que um valor lhes é atribuído. Assim isso:

```java
primeiro =0; ultimo = primeiro+quantidadeFatiasPorThread;
```

Torna-se isso:

```java
int primeiro = 0;
int ultimo = primeiro + quantidadeFatiasPorThread;
```

4. Uma vez que `primeiro` e `ultimo` não são variáveis `final` (e nem efetivamente-`final`, uma vez que sofrem mutação), o compilador vai reclamar de estas variáveis estar sendo utilizadas dentro do código da classe anônima. Portanto vou transformar isso:

```java
        arrayFutureTasks[i] = new FutureTask<Integer>(new Callable<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call() {
                return FutureTaskDemo.calcularQuantidadeDivisivelSerial(primeiro, ultimo, divisor);
            }
        });
```

Nisso:

```
        int primeiroFinal = primeiro;
        int ultimoFinal = ultimo;
        arrayFutureTasks[i] = new FutureTask<>(() -> calcularQuantidadeDivisivelSerial(primeiroFinal, ultimoFinal, divisor));
```

E já aproveitei para utilizar lambda-expression ao invés de classe anônima aí em cima.

5. A variável `arrayFutureTasks` não foi declarada. Portanto vou trocar isso:

```java
    arrayFutureTasks = new FutureTask[threadNum];
```

Por isso:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    FutureTask<Integer>[] arrayFutureTasks = (FutureTask<Integer>[]) new FutureTask<?>[threadNum];
```

---

Agora o seu código deve estar compilável, mas apresentando resultados incorretos. Não há nada de errado nele referente às threads ou ao `FutureTask`. **O seu problema é que o seu código tem uma série de erros matemáticos.**

Vamos tentar arrumar tudo:

6. O parâmetro `first` não é usado em lugar nenhum. Suponho que você queria que fosse usado para calcular os valores da primeira fatia a ser computada, caso contrário **o código irá produzir um resultado incorreto se o primeiro número da faixa não for o zero**. Portanto isso:

```java
    int primeiro = 0;
    int ultimo = primeiro + quantidadeFatiasPorThread;
```

Torna-se isso:

```java
    int primeiro = first;
    int ultimo = primeiro + quantidadeFatiasPorThread;
```

7. **O tamanho da primeira fatia está errado.** O motivo disso é a forma como a variável `ultimo` tem o seu primeiro valor computado. Por exemplo, se `primeiro` for igual a 5 e `quantidadeFatiasPorThread` for igual a 4, então teremos que:

> ultimo = primeiro + quantidadeFatiasPorThread = 5 + 4 = 9

E portanto a primeira fatia tem os elementos [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], ou seja 5 elementos. No entanto o fato da fatia ter 5 elementos está contrariando o propósito da variável `quantidadeFatiasPorThread` que tem como valor 4. Eis a solução:

```java
    int primeiro = first;
    int ultimo = primeiro + quantidadeFatiasPorThread - 1;
```

8. O seu cálculo no tamanho da fatia tem problemas. O primeiro é que como você não usa o `first` nele, e portanto se o `first` for maior que zero, os valores inferiores ao `first` serão incorretamente considerados no cálculo. Se o `first` for menor que zero, os valores negativos serão incorretamente desconsiderados. Portanto, para calcular o tamanho da fatia eu tenho que levar em conta apenas os elementos entre o `first` e o `last`. E portanto isso:

```java
    int quantidadeFatiasPorThread =  (last / threadNum);
```

Torna-se isso:

```java
    int quantidadeFatiasPorThread = (last - first + 1) / threadNum;
```

Talvez você esteja se perguntando porquê o `+ 1`. O motivo dele é que eu quero contar também o elemento do `first`. Por exemplo, se eu quiser todos os elementos de 1 até 6, então eu vou querer estes elementos: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], mas se eu fizer `6 - 1` o resultado é 5. Da mesma forma se eu quiser os elementos [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], eu tenho **11** elementos, e não 10 (pode contar para conferir, se você duvida). Isso daí acontece basicamente porque eu estou incluindo, e não excluindo, o elementos `first`. O propósito do `+ 1` também fica óbvio quando o `last` e o `first` têm o mesmo valor.

9. Ainda no cálculo do tamanho da fatia ainda temos mais um problema: **se a divisão não for exata, o arredondamento vai ser para baixo.** Isso faz com que no final do intervalo entre `first` e `last`, alguns números podem ficar sobrando sem entrar em fatia nenhuma. Para resolver isso você poderia usar `float` ou `double`, mas é muito mais fácil simplesmente arredondar para cima se for necessário:

```java
    int quantidadeFatiasPorThread = (last - first + 1) / threadNum;
    if ((last - first + 1) % threadNum != 0) quantidadeFatiasPorThread++;
```

10. Uma outra coisa interessante é este trecho:

```java
        if(ultimo > last){

            int quantidadeMais = ultimo - last;
            ultimo = ultimo - quantidadeMais;


        }
```

Vamos fazer um pouco de matemática:

> quantidadeMais = ultimo - last
>   ultimo2 = ultimo - quantidadeMais
>   Substituindo o quantidadeMais na segunda equação temos:
>   ultimo2 = ultimo - (ultimo - last)
>   ultimo2 = ultimo - ultimo + last
>   ultimo2 = last

E isto deveria ser algo óbvio, pois o `ultimo` não pode ser maior que o `last`, o maior valor que ele pode assumir é o `last`. Não precisa de uma fórmula mais complicada para isso. Logo:

```java
        if (ultimo > last) ultimo = last;
```

---

Agora o seu código já deve estar funcionando corretamente, mas vamos melhorar ele um pouco mais.

11. Primeiro estas instruções de debug:

```java
        System.out.println(i+" "+threadNum);
         System.out.println("primeiro :"+primeiro+" ultimo: "+ultimo);
```

Ficam bem melhor de se visualizar assim:

```java
        System.out.println("i: " + i + " threadNum: " + threadNum + " primeiro: " + primeiro + " ultimo: " + ultimo);
```

12. Vamos colocar um parâmetro a mais no método `calcularQuantidadeDivisivel` para especificar o número de threads ao invés de deixá-lo fixo como 2. Portanto isso:

```java
  public static int calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(final int first, final int last, final int divisor)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    int amount = 0;
    int threadNum = 2;
```

Torna-se isso:

```java
public static int calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(int first, int last, int divisor)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
{
    return calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(first, last, divisor, 2);
}

public static int calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(int first, int last, int divisor, int threadNum)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
{

    int amount = 0;
```

13. Por fim, agora é testar o seu código:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Caso 1: " + calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(0, 100, 9) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Caso 2: " + calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(1, 100, 9) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Caso 3: " + calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(2, 6, 3) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Caso 4: " + calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(5, 5, 3, 1) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Caso 5: " + calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(5, 7, 3, 3) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Caso 6: " + calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(5, 7, 3, 4) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Caso 7: " + calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(8, 8, 8, 4) + "\n");
    }
```

E ver a saída:

```
Quantidade: 51
i: 0 threadNum: 2 primeiro: 0 ultimo: 50
i: 1 threadNum: 2 primeiro: 51 ultimo: 100
Caso 1: 12

Quantidade: 50
i: 0 threadNum: 2 primeiro: 1 ultimo: 50
i: 1 threadNum: 2 primeiro: 51 ultimo: 100
Caso 2: 11

Quantidade: 3
i: 0 threadNum: 2 primeiro: 2 ultimo: 4
i: 1 threadNum: 2 primeiro: 5 ultimo: 6
Caso 3: 2

Quantidade: 1
i: 0 threadNum: 1 primeiro: 5 ultimo: 5
Caso 4: 0

Quantidade: 1
i: 0 threadNum: 3 primeiro: 5 ultimo: 5
i: 1 threadNum: 3 primeiro: 6 ultimo: 6
i: 2 threadNum: 3 primeiro: 7 ultimo: 7
Caso 5: 1

Quantidade: 1
i: 0 threadNum: 4 primeiro: 5 ultimo: 5
i: 1 threadNum: 4 primeiro: 6 ultimo: 6
i: 2 threadNum: 4 primeiro: 7 ultimo: 7
i: 3 threadNum: 4 primeiro: 8 ultimo: 7
Caso 6: 1

Quantidade: 1
i: 0 threadNum: 4 primeiro: 8 ultimo: 8
i: 1 threadNum: 4 primeiro: 9 ultimo: 8
i: 2 threadNum: 4 primeiro: 9 ultimo: 8
i: 3 threadNum: 4 primeiro: 9 ultimo: 8
Caso 7: 1
```

---

E aqui vai o código completo:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

public class FutureTaskDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Caso 1: " + calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(0, 100, 9) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Caso 2: " + calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(1, 100, 9) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Caso 3: " + calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(2, 6, 3) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Caso 4: " + calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(5, 5, 3, 1) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Caso 5: " + calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(5, 7, 3, 3) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Caso 6: " + calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(5, 7, 3, 4) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Caso 7: " + calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(8, 8, 8, 4) + "\n");
    }

    public static int calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(int first, int last, int divisor)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {
        return calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(first, last, divisor, 2);
    }

    public static int calcularQuantidadeDivisivel(int first, int last, int divisor, int threadNum)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {
        int amount = 0;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadNum);
        List<FutureTask<Integer>> taskList = new ArrayList<>(threadNum);

        int quantidadeFatiasPorThread = (last - first + 1) / threadNum;
        if ((last - first + 1) % threadNum != 0) quantidadeFatiasPorThread++;

        System.out.println("Quantidade: " + quantidadeFatiasPorThread);
        int primeiro = first;
        int ultimo = primeiro + quantidadeFatiasPorThread - 1;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        FutureTask<Integer>[] arrayFutureTasks = (FutureTask<Integer>[]) new FutureTask<?>[threadNum];

        for (int i = 0; i < threadNum; i++) {
            System.out.println("i: " + i + " threadNum: " + threadNum + " primeiro: " + primeiro + " ultimo: " + ultimo);
            int primeiroFinal = primeiro;
            int ultimoFinal = ultimo;
            arrayFutureTasks[i] = new FutureTask<>(() -> calcularQuantidadeDivisivelSerial(primeiroFinal, ultimoFinal, divisor));

            taskList.add(arrayFutureTasks[i]);
            executor.execute(arrayFutureTasks[i]);

            primeiro = ultimo + 1;
            ultimo += quantidadeFatiasPorThread;
            if (ultimo > last) ultimo = last;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < threadNum; j++) {
            FutureTask<Integer> futureTask = taskList.get(j);
            amount += futureTask.get();
        }

        executor.shutdown();

        return amount;
    }

    public static int calcularQuantidadeDivisivelSerial(int first, int last, int divisor) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
            if (i % divisor == 0) result++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

---

Ainda há mais algumas melhorias que eu posso sugerir além disso, mas que fica para você implementar:

14. Note que nos casos aonde há mais threads do que números no intervalo entre `first` e `last`, as threads excedentes acabam tendo o valor do `primeiro` como sendo `ultimo + 1`. Isso não é prejudicial, pois fará com que o método `calcularQuantidadeDivisivelSerial` retorne zero, mas acaba por criar threads desnecessárias. Se quiser arrumar isso, é só você restringir o valor do `threadNum` para nunca ser maior que `last - first + 1`.
15. Uma outra melhoria que você deveria fazer é colocar o `executor.shutdown();` dentro de um bloco `finally` com o resto do método dentro do bloco `try`. Caso contrário, se por algum motivo ocorrer uma exceção, o seu `executor` não vai virar um tipo de *memory-leak*.
16. Validar os parâmetros adequadamente: Não deixar o `divisor` ser zero, certificar-se de que `first <= last` e certificar-se que `threadNum > 0`.

Comment: Muito obrigado por compartilhar seu conhecimento!